# How to pass arguments from file?

Tags: python

I have small python script like this:

```
import sys
import subprocess

resource_names = sys.argv[1:]
for resource in resource_names:
    command = "terraform taint " + resource
    p = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
print(sys.argv)
```

I need able to pass arguments from file:

```
argument1
argument2
argument3
```

In expectation script should be work like this:

```
python script.py file-with-arguments
```

Comment: Why don't you just pass the file and read it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is make a txt file with arguments in each line. Pass that filename as an argument and readlines.

```
import sys
import subprocess

fileName = sys.argv[1]

with open(fileName,'r') as f:
    resource_names = f.readlines()
    f.close()

for resource in resource_names:
    command = "terraform taint " + resource
    p = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
print(sys.argv)
```

Comment: You can even drop that `f.close()`

Comment: Nope, that f.close() is important for security resons. if we do not close a file then it will be still open in the programme still the code runs. and penetraters can use that file binary to open a bash shell and gain root. that file binary MUST be closed. that's a good practice.

Comment: You're mistaken. It's closed as soon as the `with`-block is exited (i.e., directly after the lines have been read, if you drop the redundant `f.close()`). That's the purpose of using a context manager when opening a file, to make sure that the file is closed no matter what happens. Taking your example above, what do you think will happen if `f.readlines()` raises an exception? `f.close()` will _not_ even be called then. Either put the `f.close()` in a `finally` block or use a context manager, no need to use a context manager _and_ `f.close()` in the above example.